# nodejs execute recurrent job/task from database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, task

I'm developing an app in which users can submit their jobs/tasks to run it programatically every X minutes for later notifications. I'm storing the jobs/tasks in mongodb and here is how I'm executing the jobs:

1. I have a setInterval that executes the function each X minutes.
2. This function make a query to the mongodb with the jobs/tasks and
   store the result to an array.
3. For each element in the array, execute an action and do some stuff.

So, for now, I have a few jobs/tasks stored in the database and the performance is not a problem, but I don't think this method is not the best way to do that because the query can take too long if database grows.

I read about KUE, Agenta, etc... maybe something that attacks the database every X minutes and process each entry without query first for the entries?

¿Some advice?

Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a good thing to use [Cron Jobs](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron) for.